# Python- Labeling items in a list by year

Tags: python

Basically I am writing a program that reads a text file and places each line from the file into a list. The file lists the population, in thousands, of the United States during the years 1950 - 1990. The file, however, does not list the year, so I need my program to label each population number with a year.

My assignment is:

"You are to write a program (name it Analysis_population.py) that will read the contents of the file above into a list, and calculate and display:

- The average annual change in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 (inclusive)
- The year with the greatest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 (inclusive)
- The year with the the smallest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 (inclusive)"

I have everything working except for the year label.

My code so far is as follows:

```
year = 1950

with open("USPopulation.txt", "r") as f:
    popList = [line.strip() for line in f]
    popList = [ int(x) for x in popList ]
for x in popList:
    year = year + 1

diff = [abs(j-i) for i,j in zip(popList, popList[1:])]
maxDiff = max(abs(x - y) for (x, y) in zip(popList[1:], popList[:-1]))
minDiff = min(abs(x - y) for (x, y) in zip(popList[1:], popList[:-1]))

print("The average annual change in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is:\n",
          (sum(diff)/len(diff)))

print("\nThe year with the greatest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is:",
          year, "-", year + 1, "with an increase of", maxDiff, "people.")

minDiff = min(abs(x - y) for (x, y) in zip(popList[1:], popList[:-1]))
print("\nThe year with the smallest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is:",
          year, "-", year + 1, "with an increase of", minDiff, "people.")
```

The output that I get is:

```
The average annual change in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is:
 2443.875

The year with the greatest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is: 1991 - 1992 with an increase of 3185 people.

The year with the smallest increase in population during the time period 1950 - 1990 is: 1991 - 1992 with an increase of 1881 people.
```

As you can see, it outputs the same, incorrect year each time. 
Any help with correcting this would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a link to the text file](https://ufile.io/f9e45)

Comment: We can't actually access that text file, it is behind a log-in wall.

Comment: Canvas is not a public-access site.  Also, please read the posting guidelines: your question must be self-contained for proper archiving.

Comment: Text file has been fixed